# Laravel: Class declaration Compatible error

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-5.6

I am using laravel 5.6, when create controller and when run controller through route, I am facing error like

**Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\XyzController::xyz(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) should be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::xyz($job)**

My Code is

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class XyzController extends Controller
{

    public function xyz(Request $request)
    {
        return view('xyz.xyz');
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the question you are looking for an answer for?

Comment: when i had create controller file through command and then create route and blade file and in controller create function as above shown but now its not working proper.

Answer (score 1):

Missing route parameter: $job

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class XyzController extends Controller
{

    public function xyz(Request $request, $job)
    {
        return view('xyz.xyz');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The base Controller that `XyzController` extends from defines a method named `xyz` with a different signature than the one you are defining.

You will need to adjust the method in `XyzController` to match the signature of `xyz` in the base Controller or adjust the base Controller to have a different signature.

Example of the problem:

```php
class A
{
    public function xyz($obj) {}
}

class B extends A
{
    public function xyz(Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {}
}
```

> `Declaration of B::xyz(Illuminate/Http/Request $request) should be compatible with A::xyz($obj)`

Answer (score -2):

You forgot to use controller?

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller as Controller